# PHP fgetcsv() search and overwrite file

Tags: php, search, overwrite, fgetcsv

I have a .csv file with "code" and "description". I want to search the .csv and if it finds a duplicate "code", replace the whole row.

ie. of csv file:

```
code          description
STA-101       A great product
STA-102       Terrible Product
```

If it were to find "STA-102" replace description with something, ie:

```
code          description
STA-101       A great product
STA-102       OK Product
```

These are dynamic so I need an if statement.  Can this be done using `fgetcsv()`?
The below doesn't work but its all I know right now:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("formTest.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($data[$c] = "STA-102") {
          $data[$c] = "OK Product"; }
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

In order to write to my file to begin with, I have:

```
$code = $_POST['CODE'];
$description = $_POST['DESC']; 

if ($_POST) {
    $csvData = $code . "," . $description. "\n";
    $fp = fopen("formTest.csv","ab"); 

    if($fp){
    fwrite($fp,$csvData);
    fclose($fp); }
}
```

How can I incorporate what I have above with the if statement to overwrite the code if it needs be?

Comment: It's "PHP", not "PhP" or "Php" and certainly *never* "pHp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the separator is [tab] (not ',').

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
```

At the beggining put:

```
$res = "";
```

Also instead of

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    if ($data[$c] = "STA-102") {
        $data[$c] = "OK Product"; }
    }
    echo $data[$c];
```

I think you want

```
if ($data[0] == "STA-102") {
    $data[1] = "OK Product";
}
$res .= implode('\t', $data) . "\n";
```

and after fclose($handle);

```
$handle = fopen("formTest.csv", "w"));
fwrite($handle, $res);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: This only gets it to echo.  How can I replace what I have in the csv file at that location using `fwrite`?

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't get it to work.  I have updated my question above to incorporate how I am currently writing to the file.